# How to know when all my threads have finished executing when in recursive method?

Tags: c#, recursion, console-application, parallel.foreach, parallel.for

I have been working on a webscraping project.

I am having two issues, one being presenting the number of urls processed as percentage  but a far larger issue is that I can not figure out how I know when all the threads i am creating are totaly finished.

**NOTE**: I am aware of that the a parallel foreach once done  moves on BUT this is within a **recursive** method.

My code below:

```
    public async Task Scrape(string url)
    {
        var page = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            page = await _service.Get(url);

            if (page != string.Empty)
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(page))
                {

                    Parallel.For(0, regex.Matches(page).Count,
                        index =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (regex.Matches(page)[index].Groups[1].Value.StartsWith("/"))
                                {
                                    var match = regex.Matches(page)[index].Groups[1].Value.ToLower();
                                    if (!links.Contains(BaseUrl + match) && !Visitedlinks.Contains(BaseUrl + match))
                                    {
                                        Uri ValidUri = WebPageValidator.GetUrl(match);
                                        if (ValidUri != null && HostUrls.Contains(ValidUri.Host))
                                            links.Enqueue(match.Replace(".html", ""));
                                        else
                                            links.Enqueue(BaseUrl + match.Replace(".html", ""));

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                log.Error("Error occured: " + e.Message);
                                Console.WriteLine("Error occured, check log for further details."); ;
                            }
                        });

                WebPageInternalHandler.SavePage(page, url);
                var context = CustomSynchronizationContext.GetSynchronizationContext();

                Parallel.ForEach(links, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 25 },
                    webpage =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (WebPageValidator.ValidUrl(webpage))
                            {
                                string linkToProcess = webpage;
                                if (links.TryDequeue(out linkToProcess) && !Visitedlinks.Contains(linkToProcess))
                                {

                                        ShowPercentProgress();
                                        Thread.Sleep(15);
                                        Visitedlinks.Enqueue(linkToProcess);
                                        Task d = Scrape(linkToProcess);
                                        Console.Clear();


                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            log.Error("Error occured: " + e.Message);
                            Console.WriteLine("Error occured, check log for further details.");
                        }
                    });

                Console.WriteLine("parallel finished");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Error occured: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Error occured, check log for further details.");
        }

    }
```

**NOTE** that `Scrape` gets called multiple times(recursive)

call the method like this:

```
    public Task ExecuteScrape()
    {
        var context = CustomSynchronizationContext.GetSynchronizationContext();
        Scrape(BaseUrl).ContinueWith(x => {

            Visitedlinks.Enqueue(BaseUrl);
        }, context).Wait();

        return null;
    }
```

which in turn gets called like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunScrapper();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void RunScrapper()
    {
        try
        {

            _scrapper.ExecuteScrape();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

my result:

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: It's effectively impossible to show a meaningful percentage of completion. You could have 5 urls. You've processed 4. You're at 80%. Then that last url returns 400 more urls. So you weren't really at 80%, you're tentatively at 1%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Is it ethical for me to answer a question about web page scraping?)

Don't call `Scrape` recursively. Place the list of urls you want to scrape in a `ConcurrentQueue` and begin processing that queue. As the process of scraping a page returns more urls, just add them into the same queue.

I wouldn't use just a string, either. I recommend creating a class like

```
public class UrlToScrape //because naming things is hard
{        
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Depth { get; set; }
}
```

Regardless of how you execute this it's recursive, so you have to somehow keep track of how many levels deep you are. A website could deliberately generate URLs that send you into infinite recursion. (If they did this then they don't want you scraping their site. Does anybody want people scraping their site?)

When your queue is empty that doesn't mean you're done. The queue could be empty, but the process of scraping the last url dequeued could still add more items back into that queue, so you need a way to account for that.

You could use a thread safe counter (`int` using `Interlocked.Increment/Decrement`) that you increment when you start processing a url and decrement when you finish. You're done when the queue is empty *and* the count of in-process urls is zero.

**This is a very rough model to illustrate the concept**, not what I'd call a refined solution. For example, you still need to account for exception handling, and I have no idea where the results go, etc.

```
public class UrlScraper
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<UrlToScrape> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<UrlToScrape>();
    private int _inProcessUrlCounter;
    private readonly List<string> _processedUrls = new List<string>();

    public UrlScraper(IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(new UrlToScrape {Url = url, Depth = 1});
        }
    }

    public void ScrapeUrls()
    {
        while (_queue.TryDequeue(out var dequeuedUrl) || _inProcessUrlCounter > 0)
        {
            if (dequeuedUrl != null)
            {
                // Make sure you don't go more levels deep than you want to.
                if (dequeuedUrl.Depth > 5) continue;
                if (_processedUrls.Contains(dequeuedUrl.Url)) continue;

                _processedUrls.Add(dequeuedUrl.Url);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _inProcessUrlCounter);
                var url = dequeuedUrl;
                Task.Run(() => ProcessUrl(url));
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessUrl(UrlToScrape url)
    {
        try
        {
            // As the process discovers more urls to scrape,
            // pretend that this is one of those new urls.
            var someNewUrl = "http://discovered";
            _queue.Enqueue(new UrlToScrape { Url = someNewUrl, Depth = url.Depth + 1 });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // whatever you want to do with this
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _inProcessUrlCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

If I was doing this for real the `ProcessUrl` method would be its own class, and it would take HTML, not a URL. In this form it's difficult to unit test. If it were in a separate class then you could pass in HTML, verify that it outputs results somewhere, and that it calls a method to enqueue new URLs it finds.

It's also not a bad idea to maintain the queue as a database table instead. Otherwise if you're processing a bunch of urls and you have to stop, you'd have start all over again.

Comment: I am attempting to do it this way. As far as depth goes I check the urls that it always has a baseUrl so that I dont wander of to infinity. I am not 100% sure if this can be made to work as multiple process? like I hade a parallel foreach. I will experiment and come back to you. FYI your " not so "refined solution" is more refined than mine if you ask me.  Thank you!

Comment: Even if the url matches a given base url, a site can cause infinite recursion. They just add random urls, and those urls all return the same page which is full of more random urls. They don't need to create a new page to have a new url, so they can have an infinite number of pages.

Comment: true but the one I am scarping has a specific number of pages. Its a challange to get the correct number. I assume that my solution has the correct number but other issues which I described are in the way.
The challange/assignment here is to get all pages under a specific baseurl. 
Still trying to apply this, will accept once I am done.  hope I can keep this alive for possible future guidence if I cant make it work.

Comment: If I could i would upvote this answer to infinity. Not only did it work with helping me get the final output out when all was finished but I also managed to show the precentage in a nice way. I will be updating this with my own answer to show my final solution with useful links that helped me understand your answer better. Rare to get a detailed and helpful answer like this, Thank you very much!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add all tasks `Task d` to some type of concurrent collection you thread through all recursive calls (via method argument) and then simply call `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait()`?

You'd need an intermediate method (makes it cleaner) that launches the base `Scrape` call and passes in the empty task collection. When the base call returns you have in hand all tasks and you simply wait them out.

```
public async Task Scrape (
    string url) {
    var tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Task>();

    //call your implementation but
    //change it so that you add
    //all launched tasks d to tasks
    Scrape(url, tasks);
    
    //1st option: Wait().
    //This will block caller
    //until all tasks finish 
    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait(); 

    
    //or 2nd option: await 
    //this won't block and will return to caller.
    //Once all tasks are finished method
    //will resume in WriteLine
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Finished!"); }
```

Simple rule: if you want to know when something finishes, the first step is to *keep track* of it. In your current implementation you are essentially firing and forgetting all launched tasks...

Comment: Ill be honest my experience with concurrent lists and task is not something i would brag about. Could i bother you with a more detailed example, you might be on to something here

Comment: as an edit i dont exactly know why this is down voted?